# urls for images in meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I've recently switched from PHP to JS Meteor+ReactJS. I've started my first project and almost instantly got a bump in the road.

I cannot seem to get image in my scss file to work. Same with trying to get to it via url in my browser. In the browser I get flow-router error about missing path. Scss doesn't give me any errors just doesn't work.

I've tried every possible link variation I've found online.

absolute_path, relative_path, {}absolute_path, {}relative_path, even just putting the image in the same directory as the scss and linking to it in the same directory. Nothing seems to work.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put images and other shared content for the client in your project's `public` directory. `public` gets mapped to `/` so you can refer to them with `<img src='/images/mypicture.png'>`

If you want an images directory then put them in `public/images` and refer to them as `<img src='/images/mypicture.png'>`